# Increasing the value printed

Tags: php, html

I wrote this code and I want to increase the printed value but the next value is increasing one. For example when program choose value "Anıl Efe Çoban" it should increase one to "Anıl Efe Çoban" ' s value. But it is increasing next rand's value.  I can not find the error, Where is the problem? I'm waiting your answers.

```
$deger = 0;
echo "<div align= 'center'>";
echo "<h2> Birini Seçmek Zorundasın </h2>";
echo "</div>";
$kisiler= Array("Anıl Efe Çoban", "Mert Yüksel", "Emre Çelik", "Eren 
Şimşek", "Yiğit Gölebatmaz");
$kisiler_rand= $kisiler[array_rand($kisiler)]; # random chosing
$kisiler_randd= $kisiler_rand;
echo "<div id= 'karsilastirma1'>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<div align= 'center'>";
echo $kisiler_randd;
echo "<form method= 'POST'>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<input type= 'submit' name= 'cekici' value= 'Çekici'>". " ";
echo "<input type= 'submit' name= 'zeki' value= 'Zeki'>". " ";
echo "<input type= 'submit' name= 'dedikoducu' value= 'Dedikoducu'>". " ";
echo "<input type= 'submit' name= 'neseli' value= 'Neşeli'>". " ";


if($kisiler_randd== "Anıl Efe Çoban"){ # What is the randd
        if(isset($_POST['cekici'])){
            $sql= "SELECT * FROM benalmash WHERE isim= 'Anil_cekicilik';"; 
            $result= mysqli_query($baglan, $sql);
            $resultCheck= mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($resultCheck > 0){
                $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $deger= $row["deger"];
                $deger++;
                $sqll= "UPDATE benalmash SET deger= $deger WHERE isim= 
     'Anil_cekicilik';";
                $istek= mysqli_query($baglan, $sqll);
        }
    }
}


    if($kisiler_randd== "Emre Çelik"){
       if(isset($_POST['cekici'])){
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM benalmash WHERE isim= 'Emre_cekicilik';"; 
        $result= mysqli_query($baglan, $sql);
        $resultCheck= mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($resultCheck > 0){
        $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $deger= $row["deger"];
        $deger++;
        $sqll= "UPDATE benalmash SET deger= $deger WHERE isim= 
      'Emre_cekicilik';";
        $istek= mysqli_query($baglan, $sqll);
        }
    }
}


if($kisiler_randd== "Eren Şimşek"){
    if(isset($_POST['cekici'])){
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM benalmash WHERE isim= 'Eren_cekicilik';"; 
        $result= mysqli_query($baglan, $sql);
        $resultCheck= mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($resultCheck > 0){
            $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $deger= $row["deger"];
            $deger++;
            $sqll= "UPDATE benalmash SET deger= $deger WHERE isim= 
    'Eren_cekicilik';";
            $istek= mysqli_query($baglan, $sqll);
        }
    }
}


if($kisiler_randd== "Yiğit Gölebatmaz"){
    if(isset($_POST['cekici'])){
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM benalmash WHERE isim= 'Yigit_cekicilik';"; 
        $result= mysqli_query($baglan, $sql);
        $resultCheck= mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($resultCheck > 0){
            $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $deger= $row["deger"];
            $deger++;
            $sqll= "UPDATE benalmash SET deger= $deger WHERE isim= 
     'Yigit_cekicilik';";
            $istek= mysqli_query($baglan, $sqll);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I must be seen things, but I could't find a closing tag for `<form>`

Comment: How to increase 1 to a string?

Comment: @Cid I'm created 2 columns in my table. Those are deger and isim (deger is value, type is int and isim means name). When user press button "Çekicilik", i want to increase isim_cekicilik value.

Comment: Well, that's a bit complicated to read since this isn't in english, thank you for the clarification

Comment: And as stated @EugeneAnisiutkin there is no `</form>`

Comment: I added </form> tag under the code, echo "<input type= 'submit' name= 'neseli' value= 'Neşeli'>". " "; but problem is still exist.

Comment: I hadn't noticed it strait away, but several things: move all your php logic before HTML; Check where `<form method= 'POST'>` redirects you to, the and is `$_POST` var set at all. Also it should be `<form method= "POST">` at least, as far as I know. Right now you problem is that the Post form is not working

Comment: I can't post a full answer right now, I have no tools to test it. In about 10-12 hours, i'll post an answer if there won't be one by that time.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin Ok, i will wait

Comment: https://youtu.be/HMvN2BN3lOs

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin

Comment: i'll look into it in the evening. No tools to test right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd probably be easier and faster if you just increment the value without first getting it.

```sql
UPDATE `benalmash` SET `deger` = `deger` + 1 WHERE `isim` = 'Emre_cekicilik';
```

But your problem is, that when submitting the form, it generates a new random value. So put the initial one in a hidden form field to be able to reference it later in the query.

For sake of completeness, here's a probably working example (untested):

```php
<?php
$names = ["Anıl Efe Çoban", "Mert Yüksel", "Emre Çelik", "Eren Şimşek", "Yiğit Gölebatmaz"];
$random_id = array_rand($names);
$random_name = $names[$random_id];

if (isset($_POST['increment']) && isset($_POST['random_name'])) {
    // you should probably have another column with the complete name...
    $first_name = strtok($_POST['random_name'], ' '); // get first name
    // query should happen with PDO to prevent sql injections. do not put this into production!
    mysqli_query("UPDATE `benalmash` SET `deger` = `deger` + 1 WHERE `isim` = '" . $first_name . "_cekicilik';");
}
?>
<form id="myform" action="" method="post">
    <!-- add random name as hidden field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="random_name" value="<?php echo $random_name; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="increment" value="increment <?php echo $random_name; ?> by one">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $form = $(this);
        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function() {
            var name = $form.find('input[name='random_name']').val();
            alert('increased ' + name + ' by one');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The code provided, included form usage. Also it was stated that the use of button is desired. That imlies that user want's or has to use POST form and a button, which means also means usage of `GET` and `POST`. The part you provided fixes only SQL query, a bit. But the query is not the  main problem there.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin The question is how to increase a value. The problem however was that the random name was not saved in the form. I added a demo to see what I mean.

Comment: Now it looks better =). I have no tools on me to test right now, so i couldn't give a full answer myself, but looks like a workable solution. I will be solving this myself just out of curiosity a bit later, when i have the tools =)

Comment: @MichaelBolli That is awesome! But i do not understand why did you use this script? What does this scripts do?

Comment: @OllieMcFly The code is meant as a substitute for your code. You mean why I put the Javascript? I somehow thought you had an asynchronous request in your post; seems like I dreamed a bit...

Comment: This is no problem, Because my code is working well now. You're boss, thank you :))